# Create an image thumbnail in Android

Tags: android

Given a path to an image file, what's the best way (on the fly) to create a thumbnail for that image?

The images would be around 200-300px squared. My initial thought was to just load a small region of the image, this works well but doesn't always look so great.

```
BitmapRegionDecoder decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(new FileInputStream(file),false);
return decoder.decodeRegion(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100),null);
```

Comment: Why "on the fly"? Caching would speed things up. And for "best way" - there's no best way as it depends on images. Scaling down is most universal approach, but cropped (or cropped centered) might work too. I'd scale image down and write thumbnail to the cache for further reuse

Comment: Caching would speed up after the initial load but the thumbnails are likely to only be viewed once, negating any benefit from saving for future loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, the images were all roughly the same size (around 200px squared). Using the BitmapRegionDecoder I ended up loading a 100px thumbnail that was centred, this looks great and doesn't involve any resizing.